# Issue when integrate files with BUILD_PREBUILT and PRODUCT_COPY_FILES in Android

Tags: android, makefile

I need set two prebuilt files into android,
In Android.mk, I tried two ways,

First,

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := start.json
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER  := Open Source
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS   := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS  := ETC
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := ../../.././target/product/vendor/etc/myconfig/start.json
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH   := $(PRODUCT_OUT)/$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_VENDOR)/etc/myconfig/
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := myapp.bin
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER  := Open Source
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS   := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS  := ETC
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := ../../.././target/product/vendor/etc/myapp.bin
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH   := $(PRODUCT_OUT)/$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_VENDOR)/etc/
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Second,

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    device/myapp/odm/mydebug/start.json:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_ODM)/etc/myconfig/start.json \
    device/myapp/odm/mydebug/myapp.bin:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_ODM)/etc/myapp.bin
```

In the first config, it seems build system generate(or copy) files into output path at first, then integrate them into dedicated file partition in android;

In the second config, it looks like the action is just do a file copy only, simple and clear. However, I am not sure if this will work.

Any guys know the difference between the two configurations above in details?

for LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS flag, based on google explanation, is only used for specifying the intermediate location for storing prebuilt files during system building. So, can I set LOCAL_MODULE_PATH to any path I want?

Comment: Is my description too obscure to get the meaning or too complicated to get an anwser? If any body know why, just comment here, I will adjust the description, thanks.